# Difficulty of testing linearity in regression

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit

In [Statistical Modeling: The Two Cultures](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-3/Statistical-Modeling--The-Two-Cultures-with-comments-and-a/10.1214/ss/1009213726.full) Leo Breiman writes

> Current applied practice is to check the data model fit using goodness-of-fit tests and residual analysis. At one point, some years ago, I set up a simulated regression problem in seven dimensions with a controlled amount of nonlinearity. Standard tests of goodness-of-fit did not reject linearity until the nonlinearity was extreme.

Breiman doesn't give the details of his simulation. He references a paper that he says gives theoretical justification for his observation, but the paper is unpublished.

Has anyone seen a published simulation result or theoretical paper to support Breiman's claim?

Comment: Extreme is difficult to judge, every function approaches linear over some range; as we know from the Taylor Series decomposition. Why wouldn't Burnham and Anderson's information criterion approach to model selection  serve this problem well?

Answer (score 13):

I created a simulation that would answer to Breiman's description and found only the obvious: **the result depends on the context and on what is meant by "extreme."**

An awful lot could be said, but let me limit it to just one example conducted by means of easily modified `R` code for interested readers to use in their own investigations.  This code begins by setting up a design matrix consisting of approximately uniformly distributed independent values that are approximately orthogonal (so that we don't get into multicollinearity problems).  It computes a single quadratic (i.e., nonlinear) interaction between the first two variables: this is only one of many kinds of "nonlinearities" that could be studied, but at least it is a common, well-understood one.  Then it standardizes everything so that the coefficients will be comparable:

```
set.seed(41)
p <- 7                                            # Dimensions
n <- 2^p                                          # Observations
x <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, lapply(as.list(1:p), function(i) c(-1,1))))
x <- x + runif(n*p, min=-1, max=1)
x <- cbind(x, x.12 = x[,1]*x[,2])                 # The nonlinear part
x <- apply(x, 2, function(y) (y - mean(y))/sd(y)) # Standardization
```

For the base OLS model (without nonlinearity) we must specify some coefficients and the standard deviation of the residual error.  Here is a set of unit coefficients and a comparable SD:

```
beta <- rep(c(1,-1), p)[1:p]
sd <- 1
```

To illustrate the situation, here is one hard-coded iteration of the simulation.  It generates the dependent variable, summarizes its values, displays the full correlation matrix of all the variables (including the interaction), and displays a scatterplot matrix.  Then it performs the OLS regression.  In the following, the interaction coefficient of $1/4$ is substantially smaller than any of the other coefficients (all equal to $1$ or $-1$), so it would be difficult to call it "extreme":

```
gamma = 1/4          # The standardized interaction term
df <- data.frame(x)
df$y <- x %*% c(beta, gamma) + rnorm(n, sd=sd)
summary(df)
cor(df)*100
plot(df, lower.panel=function(x,y) lines(lowess(y~x)), 
     upper.panel=function(x,y) points(x,y, pch=".", cex=4))
summary(lm(df$y ~ x))
```

Rather than wade through all the output here, let's *look* at these data using the output of the `plot` command:

[image: SPM]

The lowess traces on the lower triangle show essentially no linear relationship between the interaction (`x.12`) and the dependent variable (`y`) and modest linear relationships between the other variables and `y`.  The OLS results confirm that; the interaction is scarcely significant:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.0263     0.0828    0.32    0.751    
xVar1         0.9947     0.0833   11.94   <2e-16 ***
xVar2        -0.8713     0.0842  -10.35   <2e-16 ***
xVar3         1.0709     0.0836   12.81   <2e-16 ***
xVar4        -1.0007     0.0840  -11.92   <2e-16 ***
xVar5         1.0233     0.0836   12.24   <2e-16 ***
xVar6        -0.9514     0.0835  -11.40   <2e-16 ***
xVar7         1.0482     0.0835   12.56   <2e-16 ***
xx.12         0.1902     0.0836    2.27    0.025 *
```

I will take the p-value of the interaction term as a test of nonlinearity: when this p-value is sufficiently low (you can choose just how low), we will have detected the nonlinearity.

(There's a subtlety here about what exactly we're looking for.  In practice we might need to examine all 7*6/2 = 21 possible such quadratic interactions, as well as perhaps 7 more quadratic terms, rather than focusing on a single term as is done here.  We would want to make a correction for these 28 inter-related tests.  I do not explicitly make this correction here, because instead I display the simulated distribution of the p-values.  You can read the detection rates directly from the histograms at the end based on *your* thresholds of significance.)

But let's not do this analysis just once; let's do it lots of times, generating new values of `y` in each iteration according to the same model and the same design matrix.  To accomplish this, we use a function to carry out one iteration and return the p-value of the interaction term:

```
test <- function(gamma, sd=1) {
  y <- x %*% c(beta, gamma) + rnorm(n, sd=sd)
  fit <- summary(lm(y ~ x))
  m <- coef(fit)
  n <- dim(m)[1]
  m[n, 4]
}
```

I choose to present the simulation results as histograms of the p-values, varying the standardized coefficient `gamma` of the interaction term.  First, the histograms:

```
h <- function(g, n.trials=1000) {
  hist(replicate(n.trials, test(g, sd)), xlim=c(0,1), 
       main=toString(g), xlab="x1:x2 p-value")
}
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) # Draw a 2 by 2 panel of results
```

Now to do the work.  It takes a few seconds for 1000 trials per simulation (and four independent simulations, starting with the given value of the interaction term and successively halving it each time):

```
temp <- sapply(2^(-3:0) * gamma, h)
```

The results:

[image: Histograms]

Reading backwards from the lower right, these plots show that for *this* design matrix `x`, for *this* standard deviation of errors `sd`, and for *these* standardized coefficients `beta`, OLS can detect a standardized interaction of $1/4$ (just one-quarter the size of the other coefficients) reliably, over 80% of the time (using a 5% threshold for the p-value--recall the brief discussion about correcting for multiple comparisons, which I am now ignoring); it can often detect an interaction size of $1/8$ (about 20% of the time); it will sometimes detect an interaction of size $1/16$, and really cannot identify any smaller interactions.  Not shown here is a histogram for `gamma` equal to $1/2$, which shows that even when correcting for multiple comparisons, a quadratic interaction this large is almost surely detected.

Whether you take these interactions, which range in size from $1/32$ to $1/4$, to be "extreme" or not will depend on your perspective, on the regression situation (as expressed by `x`, `sd`, and `beta`), on how many independent tests of nonlinearity you imagine conducting, and, *pace* Breiman, whom I respect greatly, perhaps on whether you have an axe to grind.  You certainly can make it difficult for OLS to detect the nonlinearity: just inflate `sd` so it swamps the nonlinearity and simultaneously conduct many different tests for goodness of fit.

In short, **a simulation like this can prove whatever you like if you just set it up and interpret it the right way.**  That suggests the individual statistician should conduct their own explorations, suitable to the particular problems they face, in order to come to a personal and deep understanding of the capabilities and weaknesses of the procedures they are using.

Comment: +1, just FYI, I notice you write your own function to standardize your data, you may find [?scale](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scale.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @gung. I was sure such a function was around but couldn't think of its name. I'm pretty new to `R` and always appreciate such pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it gives a final answer to the question, but I would give a look at [this](http://cscs.umich.edu/~crshalizi/weblog/491.html). Especially point 2. See also the discussion in appendix A2 of the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062).

Comment: Thanks for looking, but these seem to be distribution-fitting applications rather than OLS regression.